# log4j.properties inside a jar file

Tags: java, log4j

I've made an component (lets Say SUBSCRIPTION jar) and exported it as jar file. This components includes log4j implementation and I am successfully able to generate the log file. (if ran independently).

But, when this jar (SUBSCRIPTION JAR) is used by other project/component, the log file that I mentioned (in log4j.properties of my component) is NOT getting generated.

How to do I make sure that log file generated, if my component is used by other project/component? (even if they implement log4j or not)

Here is my log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, logfile
log4j.logger.stdout=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.logger.logfile=DEBUG, logfile

log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.logfile.File=logs/subscritionLogFile.log
log4j.appender.logfile.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5p] %c:%M:%L -%X{userLoginId} %m%n
```

Note: Using Apache Log4j framework

Comment: provide the code for log4j implementation class

Comment: Also provide the java code where you have initialize your logger

Comment: static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyController.class.getName());

Comment: where log4j.properties is kept in your project

Comment: I think log4j.properties is not being loaded. try loading through system properties **log4j.configurationFile** [refer link](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)

Comment: under src\main\resource folder. (available in classpath)

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom named log4j.properties (subscriptionlog4j.properties) file in the component and make sure the component is loaded with custom log4j.properties file.

```
        try {
        InputStream input = SubscriptionController.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("subscriptionlog4j.properties");
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(input);
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(prop);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("ERROR: Unable to load subscriptionlog4j.properties");
    }
```

Note: I placed the above code in static block, so that when ever my component loaded, my custom log4j properties is loaded.